# Ajax sumit but nothing happen

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, post, submit

I have this script but nothing happen,can someone tell me what is wrong?i want to make a chat room but nothing is happen,when i press the button is stack,can someone tell me what is wrong and give me a detail about what should i do?Or someone give me another detail,please excuse me about this long post but here i cant write less details,thank you in advance

```
<?
//include("write_chat.php");
$rid = $_GET["rid"];


echo "<div id='postResults'></div>";

?>


<script>

//inregistrare postare
$('body').on('submit', '#contact-form', function(){
  $.post('index.php?page=writechat&rid=".$_GET["rid"].", $(this).serialize(), function(resp){
    alert(resp);
  });
  return false;
});

//afisare la interval de timp
setInterval(function(){
  $('#content').load(index.php?page=writechat&rid=".$_GET["rid"]');
}, 5000);







  (function($)
  {
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
          $.ajaxSetup(
          {
              cache: false,
              beforeSend: function() {
                  $('#content').hide();
                  $('#loading').show();
              },
              complete: function() {
                  $('#loading').hide();
                  $('#content').show();
              },
              success: function() {
                  $('#loading').hide();
                  $('#content').show();
              }
          });
          var $container = $("#content");
          $container.load("<?php echo "index.php?page=writechat&rid=".$_GET["rid"].""; ?>");
          var refreshId = setInterval(function()
          {
              $container.load('<?php echo "index.php?page=writechat&rid=".$_GET["rid"].""; ?>');
          }, 5000);
      });
  })(jQuery);


</script>


<body>
<div id ="content"></div>

<form  id="contact-form" class="bl_form text-center" action="<?php echo "../../index.php?page=writechat&rid=$rid"; ?>" method="post" novalidate>
  <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-
    right">
  </span>
  <span 
    class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-left">
  <textarea id="contact-message" 
    name="message" rows="5" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-
    placeholder="Message"  style="margin: 0px; width: 1210px; 
    height: 88px;" data-error-empty="<?php echo "$insert_message"; ?>"></textarea>
  </span>
  <p class="text-center"><button  name="sy2" 
    id="submit_post" type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary icon-left" data-error-
    message="Error!" data-sending-message="Sending..." data-ok-message="Message Sent"><i 
    class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Send Message</button></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" 
    id="submitted" value="true" />
  <?php echo "<postfield name=\"message\" 
    value=\"$(message)\"/>"; ?>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I don’t see you doing anything anywhere with the data you have POSTed to the server-side script.

Comment: but is not posting without refresh,i want to submit without refreshing

Comment: Well have you checked the console for errors first of all? Did you even embed jQuery? (Please show a _proper_ [mcve], then we don’t have to ask for one detail after the other in comments.)

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" </script> it is embed in head.php

Comment: i do not get any error

Comment: If it works “with refresh”, then that likely just means the form was simply submitted normally - so either your submit event handler was not bound to it correctly in the first place, or an error in that part of the code makes it terminate, and then perform the default action … (You don’t necessarily _see_ errors in console, if the page gets reloaded directly after. So make sure that you have the “preserve log” option [or similar, depending on browser] enabled.)